# Вывод всех твитов c помощью гема twitter

Tags: ruby, twitter

Здравствуйте!
Пробую парсить твитты с определенным хештегом с помощью гема [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)

Такой код работает

```
<% @client.search("#edctn -rt").each do |edu| %>
    <p><a href="<%= edu.uri %>">ссылка на твит</a></p>
    <p><%= edu.full_text %></p>
<% end %>
```

Но приходят только новые твиты? можно ли вывести старые? И не только мои твиты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## К сожалению, через Twitter API никак.

Поиск в Twitter API может показывать результаты ну очень выборочно, поскольку он производится по выборке (с неизвестными критериями) из твитов за последнюю неделю. Предположительно, в индекс они попадают, если к ним достаточно обращений, но это исключительно моя догадка о реализации.

> ### [The Search API](http://The%20Search%20API)
>
> The Twitter Search API is part of Twitter’s REST API. It allows queries **against the indices of recent or popular Tweets** and behaves similarly to, but not exactly like the Search feature available in Twitter mobile or web clients, such as Twitter.com search. **The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days**.
>
> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that **some Tweets and users may be missing from search results**. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

Они советуют Streaming API, чтобы получать всё, но он выдаёт твиты только по мере их создания (зато почти сразу). А старые твиты через него нельзя получить вообще.

Так что второй твит появится, если повезёт. **Другие же получить нельзя вообще.**